# How to add bitmap image to textview in android

Tags: android

I have the bitmap of an image. I want to place that image in the textView. How can I do that in android?

I have checked `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()`, but I can only add Drawable resources in it.

Comment: I do not want it as a background image..It should be an image in place of a text

Comment: Does it make a difference? `textView.setText("");` there will be no foreground.

Comment: than you should use `ImageView` OR do you have any special case for setting image in `TextView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set to background of textview, That can be you can add to image in textview background. If you want to add Bitmap in textview background that can be you have to convert in drawble bitmap. Below code for how to set backroud with bitmap.

```
TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
txt.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap));
```